# RSpec + Factory_Girl View Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, factory-bot

Again, seem to be stuck on a simple view test. Here's the code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "posts/show.html.erb" do
  setup do
    @post = Factory(:post)
  end

  it "should not render a canonical link rel" do
    get :show, :id => @post.id
    response.should_not have_tag("link[rel=?]", "canonical")
  end
end
```

When I do Factory(:post) from the console, no problems, creates it perfectly. But when I run this on the command line, I get the following:

```
rspec spec/views/posts/show.html.erb_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) posts/show.html.erb should not render a canonical link rel
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @post.id
     RuntimeError:
       Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
     # ./spec/views/posts/show.html.erb_spec.rb:11

Finished in 0.06532 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [before each](http://rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html):

```
before(:each) do
    @post = Factory(:post)
end
```

or

```
before do
  @post = Factory(:post)
end
```

for shorthand.

instead of the setup block.

Comment: wow, that was amazingly simple. what's the setup block for then?